# How to make a website multi language

Tags: javascript, html, xhtml

Below is my html code ...integrated with .js , I want to add multi-language option on top right corner. If someone can add that in code that will be great. I made this for lex and I dont have experience in HTML. This also captures audio and if someone can suggest on changing audio in multi-language, that will be awesome.
`

```
<html>
  <head>
    <!-- Font Dependencies -->
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,500,700|Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

    <!-- Vuetify CSS Dependencies -->
    <link href="https://unpk`enter code here`g.com/vuetify@0.16.9/dist/vuetify.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

    <!-- LexWebUi CSS from dist directory -->
    <link href="./lex-web-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <!-- page specific LexWebUi styling -->
    <style type="text/css">
      #lex-web-ui-app { display: flex; height: 100%; width: 100%; }
      body, html { overflow-y: auto; overflow-x: hidden; }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <!-- application will be dynamically mounted here -->
    <div id="lex-web-ui"></div>

    <!--
      Vue, Vuex, Vuetifiy and AWS SDK dependencies must be loaded before lex-web-ui.js.
      Loading from third party CDN for quick testing
    -->
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.5.3"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/vuex@3.0.1"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/vuetify@0.16.9"></script>
    <script src="https://sdk.amazonaws.com/js/aws-sdk-2.149.0.min.js"></script>

    <!-- LexWebUi Library from dist directory -->
    <script src="./lex-web-ui.js"></script>

    <!-- instantiate the web ui with a basic config -->
    <script>
      // LexWebUi supports numerous configuration options. Here
      // is an example using just a couple of the required options.
      var config = {
        cognito: {
          // Your Cognito Pool Id - this is required to provide AWS credentials
          poolId: ''
        },
        lex: {
          // Lex Bot Name in your account
          botName: 'demo'
        }
      };
      // load the LexWebUi component
      var lexWebUi = new LexWebUi.Loader(config);
      // instantiate Vue
      new Vue({
        el: '#lex-web-ui',
        store: lexWebUi.store,
        template: '<div id="lex-web-ui-app"><lex-web-ui/></div>',
      });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Create a map in your root called: 'language'
2. Create a file called 'en-GB.language.ini' and a folder called: 'overrides'
3. Add an empty 'index.html' in both of these folders
4. Create a file called 'en-GB.language.ini' in the folder 'overrides'
5. Set up the language file's like this:

> RO_NO_TEXT_UPDATE="Message is empty, please try again."

6. Create a `class` in your root folder 'classes' and include it in your index. name it: 'language'
7. Create a function which loads the language file. 
   7.1 Based on selected/server settings (or check 'headers') you include the overrided file after the main one
8. Create a function which can be called statically and returns the text which is called
9. exmaple code: `echo RDtext::_('RO_NO_TEXT_UPDATE')` will display: "Message is empty, please try again."

When you use RO_NO_TEXT_UPDATE in another language file, for example a dutch one, the english text would be overruled with your dutch given words: "Bericht is leeg, probeer het opnieuw."

Hopefully I can give you an idea on how to get this working properly.

Or you can get google translate working, but that would take quite a lot of progress for your server: https://packagist.org/packages/stichoza/google-translate-php

Comment: Thanks. I am able to configure

Comment: Glad to hear it. If you feel my answer helped you you could mark this answer as right. So your question can be closed

Answer (score 0):

try this google Translate API. add it to your website
https://translate.google.com/manager/website/